# Can i make a loop and listen for a key press and get this key value to a variable in C# Console Application without stop the loop

Tags: c#, .net

For example this code:

```
    while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape))
{
     //do something
}
```

But when the key is pressed instead stop i just get the key value to a variable

Comment: If you don't want the loop to end, why did you put it in the loops condition?

Comment: @Xerillio I just put it to exemplify what I wanted to do, i tried in other ways but i only made the code worse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the loop to continue, take `KeyAvailable` out of the while condition.

```
while (true)
{
    if (Console.KeyAvailable) 
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
    }
    //Do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, i tried to do something like that but it just worsened, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's another sample that might help you.

```
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
        Console.Write("type some characters (ESC to quit)> ");

        while (true)
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true); // use false to allow the characters to display
            
            if(key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You pressed ESC. The program will terminate when you press the ENTER key.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }  
            
            // do some more stuff with the key value from the key press if you want to now
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Console.ReadKey(bool)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey) returns an instance of [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo). So, you could store the result of `Console.ReadKey(bool)` in a variable of type `ConsoleKeyInfo` and use an inner `while` loop to wait for a key press.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

do
{
   while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
   {
      // Listening for a keypress...
   }

   cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
   // Do something with cki.
} while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```